# A infinite series expansion for $e^e$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How can $e^e$ be expressed in an infinite series with as much simplification as possible.

- I wrote the series of $e^x$ by keeping $x$ as $e$ and from there I also expanded every $e$ in this expansion now I was thing about expanding it further by binomial theorem but I am not able to understand how can i use binomial theorem here and how much can this be simplified in another words I am trying to write this series as simple as expansion of $e$ , is it possible and how it can be done.
- Any help will be highly appreciated , thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the Wikipedia article Bell Number, particularly  the intro and section 3.2 (Generating function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let **$f(x)=e^x$**
Then $$f^{(1)}(x)=f^{(2)}(x)=...=f^{(n)}(x)=...=e^x, \forall x\in\Bbb R.$$
Then applying Taylor's theorem we get -
$$f(x)=f(0)+xf^{(1)}(0)+\frac {x^2}{2!} f^{(2)}(0)+...+\frac {x^n}{n!} f^{(n)}(\phi), 0\lt\phi\lt1.$$
Then you will get 
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...$$
i.e. $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {x^n}{n!}$$
And hence  $$e^e=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {e^n}{n!}$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^i}{i!}}{n!}.$$

Comment: Quoting the OP: *"I wrote the series of $e^x$ by keeping $x$ as  $e$"*.

Comment: Actually first time that was my fault. I can understand that was e^e

Comment: Why are you down voting me ?

Comment: It is Lagrange's theorem or Taylor's theorem.

Answer (score 3):

$$e^e=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{e^k}{k!}=\sum_{k,\,l\ge 0}\frac{k^l}{k!l!}$$